# Integral of a determinant over a unit simplex

Tags: calculus, integration, determinant, simplex

Recalling the definition of the unit simplex

$$ \Delta^{(n)}=\lbrace (x_1,\dots,x_n)\in \mathbb{R}_+^{n} \; , \sum_{i=1}^n x_i=1  \rbrace,$$

I would like to calculate this integral for all integers $n\geq 2$

$$I(n)=\int_{\Delta^{(n)}}\mathrm{d}x_1\dots \mathrm{d}x_n \, \mathrm{det}\big[\exp \big(-\frac{(x_i-x_j)^2}{2}\big)\big]_{i,j\in [1,n]} $$

where det is the usual determinant. I tried the triangular change of variable

$$
y_1=x_1 \quad \qquad \\
y_2=x_1+x_2\quad \;\\
y_3=x_1+x_2+x_3\\
\dots\\
\dots\\
y_n=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \qquad \quad
$$

but that does not really help... 
Any guess would be welcome !

Comment: The problem as you stated has a trivial solution $ I(n)=0$ since$ \Delta^{(n)}$ has ($n$-dimensional Lebesgue) measure $0$. For $I(n)$ to be meaningful, the integral should be defined in terms of $n-1$-dimensional Lebesgue meausre.

Comment: @Song Help me, please, to find my error for $J(2).$

Comment: @Song, thanks for your comment. Originally, the representation of the integral I'm interested in is $I(n)=\int_{\mathbb{R}_+^n}\mathrm{d}x_1\dots \mathrm{d}x_n \, \delta(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i-1)\mathrm{det}\big[\exp \big(-\frac{(x_i-x_j)^2}{2}\big)\big]_{i,j\in [1,n]}$ and I did interpret the $\delta$ as a constraint leading to the simplex, perhaps it was badly formulated.

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$I_1(a,b,c,x) = \int e^{-ax^2-bx-c}\,\mathrm dx = \dfrac1{2\sqrt a}\left(\sqrt π \,e^{b^2/(4a)-c}\,\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{2ax+b}{2\sqrt a}\right)\right) + constant\tag1$$
(see also [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20e%5E(-Ax%5E2-Bx-C)%20dx)),
$$I_{0}(a,b,x) = \int e^{-a(x-b)^2}\,\mathrm dx = I_1(a,-2ab,ab^2,x) =\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{4a}}\,\mathrm{erf}\left(\sqrt a(x-b)\right) + constant,\tag2$$
$$I_{20}(a,b,x) = \int \mathrm{erf}(a(x-b))\,\mathrm dx = \dfrac1{\sqrt\pi a}e^{-a^2(x-b)^2} + (x-b)\, \mathrm{erf}(a(x-b)) + constant\tag3$$
(see also [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20erf(Ax-A%20B)%20dx)),
$$I_{21}(a,b,x) = \int(x-b) \mathrm{erf}(a(x-b))\,\mathrm dx = {\small \dfrac{\sqrt\pi(1-2a^2 (b^2-2bx+x^2))\,\mathrm{erf}(a(b-x))+2a(x-b)e^{-a^2(x-b)^2}}{4\sqrt\pi a^2}},\tag4$$
(see also [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20(x-B)erf(Ax-A%20B)%20dx)).

Then
$$J(1) = \int\limits_0^1 \,\mathrm dx_1 = 1.$$
If $n=2,$ then the simplex perimeter consists of two intervals on the axices and one slope interval $y=1-x.$

At the same time, determinant equals to
$$d_2=\begin{vmatrix}
1 & e^{-(x-y)^2}\\
e^{-(x-y)^2} & 1\\
\end{vmatrix}
=1-e^{-2(x-y)^2},$$
$$J(2) = \int\limits_0^1\left(2-2e^{-2x^2}+1-e^{-2(2x-1)^2}\right)\,\mathrm dx
=3-(2I_0(2,0,x)+I_0(8,1/2,x))\bigg|_0^1
=3-\left(\sqrt{\dfrac\pi2}\,\mathrm{erf}(\sqrt2x)+\dfrac14\sqrt{\dfrac\pi2}\,\mathrm{erf}\left(\sqrt2(2x-1)\right)\right)\bigg|_0^1 = 3-\dfrac34\sqrt{2\pi}\,\mathrm{erf}(\sqrt2) \approx 1.20557$$
(see also [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1%20(2-2e%5E(-2x%5E2)%2B1-e%5E(-2(2x-1)%5E2))%20dx)),

If $n=3,$ then the simplex surface consists of three triangles on the axices' planes and one slope triangle at the plane $x_3=1-x_1-x_2.$

At the same time, determinant equals to
$$d_3=\begin{vmatrix}
1 & e^{-(x_1-x_2)^2} & e^{-(x_1-x_3)^2} \\
e^{-(x_1-x_2)^2} & 1 & e^{-(x_2-x_3)^2}\\
e^{-(x_1-x_3)^2} & e^{-(x_2-x_3)^2} & 1\\
\end{vmatrix}
= 1+2e^{-(x_1-x_2)^2-(x_2-x_3)^2-(x_3-x_1)^2}-\left(e^{-2(x_1-x_2)^2} + e^{-2(x_2-x_3)^2} + e^{-2(x_3-x_1)^2}\right),$$

$$J(3) = 3\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^{1-x}\left(1+2e^{-(x-y)^2-y^2-x^2} - e^{y^2-x^2} - e^{-(x-y)^2-x^2}-e^{-(x-y)^2-y^2}\right)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$$
$$ + \int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^{1-x_1}\bigg(1+2e^{-(x_1-x_2)^2-(x_2-x_3)^2-(x_3-x_1)^2}-e^{-2(x_1-x_2)^2} - e^{-2(x_2-x_3)^2} - e^{-2(x_3-x_1)^2}\bigg)\,\mathrm dx_2\,\mathrm dx_1 $$
$$ = 3\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^{1-x}\left(1+2e^{-2y^2+2xy-2x^2} - e^{-x^2}e^{-y^2} - e^{-x^2}e^{-(y-x)^2}-e^{-2y^2+2xy-x^2}\right)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$$
$$ + \int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^{1-x}\bigg(1+2e^{-(y-x)^2-(2y+x-1)^2-(y+2x-1)^2} -e^{-2(y-x)^2} - e^{-2(2y+x-1)^2} - e^{-2(y+2x-1)^2}\bigg)\,\mathrm dx_2\,\mathrm dx_1 $$
$$ = 3\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^{1-x}\left(1+2e^{-2y^2+2xy-2x^2} - e^{-x^2}e^{-y^2} - e^{-y^2+2xy-2x^2}-e^{-2y^2+2xy-x^2}\right)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$$
$$+\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^{1-x}\bigg(1+2e^{-6(y^2+(x-1)y+x^2-x)-2}-e^{-2(y-x)^2} - e^{-2(2y+x-1)^2} - e^{-2(y+2x-1)^2}\bigg)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx $$
$$ = 3J_{31} + J_{32} \approx 0.0929729 + 0.00144917 = 0.09442207.$$
[Integral 1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1%20int_0%5E(1-x)%203(1%2B2e%5E%7B-(x-y)%5E2-y%5E2-x%5E2%7D%20-%20e%5E%7B-y%5E2-x%5E2%7D%20-%20e%5E%7B-(x-y)%5E2-x%5E2%7D-e%5E%7B-(x-y)%5E2-y%5E2%7D)%20dy%20dx) and [Integral 2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1%20int_0%5E(1-x)%20(1%2B2e%5E%7B-(y-x)%5E2-(2y%2Bx-1)%5E2-(y%2B2x-1)%5E2%7D-e%5E%7B-2(y-x)%5E2%7D%20-%20e%5E%7B-2(2y%2Bx-1)%5E2%7D%20-%20e%5E%7B-2(y%2B2x-1)%5E2%7D)%20dy%20dx) can be calculated using $(1)-(3).$

If $n=4,$ then the simplex hypersurface consists of four triangular pyramids on the axices' hyperplanes and one slope triangular pyramid at the hyperplane $x_4=1-x_1-x_2-x_3.$

At the same time, determinant equals to
$$d_4=\begin{vmatrix}
1 & e^{-(x-y)^2} & e^{-(x-z)^2} & e^{-(x-t)^2}\\
e^{-(y-x)^2} & 1 & e^{-(y-z)^2} & e^{-(y-t)^2}\\
e^{-(z-x)^2} & e^{-(z-y)^2} & 1 & e^{-(z-t)^2}\\
e^{-(t-x)^2} & e^{-(t-y)^2} & e^{-(t-z)^2} & 1\\
\end{vmatrix}
= e^{-(t-x)^2-(x-t)^2-(t-y)^2-(x-y)^2-(y-t)^2-(y-x)^2-(t-z)^2-(x-z)^2-(y-z)^2-(z-t)^2-(z-x)^2-(z-y)^2}\bigg(
e^{(t-y)^2+(x-y)^2+(y-t)^2+(y-x)^2+(t-z)^2+(x-z)^2+(z-t)^2+(z-x)^2}
-e^{(t-x)^2+(x-t)^2+(t-y)^2+(x-y)^2+(y-t)^2+(y-x)^2+(t-z)^2+(x-z)^2+(z-t)^2+(z-x)^2}
+e^{(t-x)^2+(x-t)^2+(t-y)^2+(x-y)^2+(y-t)^2+(t-z)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-t)^2+(z-x)^2}
-e^{(x-t)^2+(t-y)^2+(x-y)^2+(y-x)^2+(t-z)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-t)^2+(z-x)^2}
-e^{(t-x)^2+(t-y)^2+(x-y)^2+(y-t)^2+(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-t)^2+(z-x)^2}
+e^{(t-x)^2+(x-t)^2+(t-y)^2+(x-y)^2+(y-x)^2+(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-t)^2+(z-x)^2}
+e^{(t-x)^2+(x-t)^2+(t-y)^2+(y-t)^2+(y-x)^2+(t-z)^2+(x-z)^2+(z-t)^2+(z-y)^2}
-e^{(t-x)^2+(x-y)^2+(y-t)^2+(y-x)^2+(t-z)^2+(x-z)^2+(z-t)^2+(z-y)^2}
+e^{(t-x)^2+(x-t)^2+(x-y)^2+(y-x)^2+(t-z)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-t)^2+(z-y)^2}
-e^{(t-x)^2+(x-t)^2+(t-y)^2+(x-y)^2+(y-t)^2+(y-x)^2+(t-z)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-t)^2+(z-y)^2}
-e^{(t-x)^2+(x-t)^2+(t-y)^2+(y-x)^2+(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-t)^2+(z-y)^2}
+e^{(t-x)^2+(t-y)^2+(x-y)^2+(y-t)^2+(y-x)^2+(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-t)^2+(z-y)^2}
-e^{(x-t)^2+(t-y)^2+(y-t)^2+(y-x)^2+(t-z)^2+(x-z)^2+(z-x)^2+(z-y)^2}
+e^{(t-x)^2+(x-t)^2+(x-y)^2+(y-t)^2+(y-x)^2+(t-z)^2+(x-z)^2+(z-x)^2+(z-y)^2}
-e^{(t-x)^2+(x-t)^2+(x-y)^2+(y-t)^2+(t-z)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2+(z-y)^2}
+e^{(x-t)^2+(t-y)^2+(x-y)^2+(y-t)^2+(y-x)^2+(t-z)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2+(z-y)^2}
+e^{(t-x)^2+(x-t)^2+(t-y)^2+(y-t)^2+(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2+(z-y)^2}
-e^{(t-x)^2+(x-t)^2+(t-y)^2+(x-y)^2+(y-t)^2+(y-x)^2+(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2+(z-y)^2}
-e^{(t-x)^2+(x-t)^2+(t-y)^2+(y-t)^2+(t-z)^2+(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-t)^2+(z-x)^2+(z-y)^2}
+e^{(t-x)^2+(x-y)^2+(y-t)^2+(t-z)^2+(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-t)^2+(z-x)^2+(z-y)^2}
+e^{(x-t)^2+(t-y)^2+(y-x)^2+(t-z)^2+(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-t)^2+(z-x)^2+(z-y)^2}
-e^{(t-x)^2+(x-t)^2+(x-y)^2+(y-x)^2+(t-z)^2+(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-t)^2+(z-x)^2+(z-y)^2}
-e^{(t-y)^2+(x-y)^2+(y-t)^2+(y-x)^2+(t-z)^2+(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-t)^2+(z-x)^2+(z-y)^2}
+e^{(t-x)^2+(x-t)^2+(t-y)^2+(x-y)^2+(y-t)^2+(y-x)^2+(t-z)^2+(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-t)^2+(z-x)^2+(z-y)^2}\bigg).$$

And further progress becames too hard.

Comment: You seem to be integrating over the region in the positive orthant defined by $\sum_i x_i \le 1$. Note that OP (as stated) is integrating over the $(n-1)$-simplex defined by $\sum_i x_i = 1$.

Comment: @Christoph You are right. Thanks!

Comment: @Christoph First Edition.

Comment: Not sure why you are putting all this work into this when the integral asked for is just $0$ as pointed out by Song in the comments and OP doesn't care to clarify.

Comment: @Christoph Thank you, I will check my work and his  arguments

Comment: @Christoph, I tried to clarify in the first comment above the meaning of my simplex, it is indeed an $n-1$ simplex, the constraint came originally from a $\delta$ function which I interpreted as a simplex constraint.